# Equation $(x+y\sqrt{2})^6+(u+v\sqrt{2})^6=5+7\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory

Solve equation $$(x+y\sqrt{2})^6+(u+v\sqrt{2})^6=5+7\sqrt{2}$$ for $x,y,u,v$ rationals.

Sorry but I have not any idea.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: One my friend gave me this problem. May be you know a solution?